# How to authenticate local Linux user with Nginx PAM module?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos7, pam

I would like to be able to have a local Linux user authenticate with their credentials when accessing a site. I am using the ngx_http_auth_pam_module. In the nginx.conf file I have the following configuration for the location directive:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://somewebsite:5000;
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        auth_pam "Secure area";
        auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
    }
```

With the "auth_pam" and "auth_pam_service_name" syntaxes in my nginx.conf file I get prompted when accessing the site to enter in credentials. In the /etc/pam.d directory I have created an "nginx" service file with the following:

```
auth required pam_unix.so
account required pam_unix.so
```

I am running this on a CentOS 7 server. I understand that I would have to create a local Linux user and/or group and possibly provide access to the /etc/shadow file but using the tutorials I found online I am still not able to login with a local user. Would someone please be able to provide me with steps on how to get it to work so that I can login with a local Linux user when accessing the site?

Thank you, any help is appreciated and I can give more information if needed.

Answer (score 4):

The [README](https://github.com/sto/ngx_http_auth_pam_module) for this third party nginx module says:

> Note that the module runs as the web server user, so the PAM modules used must be able to authenticate the users without being root; that means that if you want to use the `pam_unix.so` module to autenticate users you need to let the web server user to read the `/etc/shadow` file if that does not scare you (on Debian like systems you can add the `www-data` user to the `shadow` group).

Note well the security implications of allowing your web server and/or web application to read the shadow file.

Comment: Thank you Michael. What would be my web server user, or how can I find out? Would it be Nginx?

Comment: @Nebek It's shown in the process list. You can also check the systemd unit or the nginx configuration file.

Comment: Sorry Michael but I am still not understanding. In my nginx configuration file, towards the top, I see the line 'user nobody'. Is 'nobody' the web server user? Should I edit this line? Also, if you can please provide me with steps on how to give the web server user permission to read the /etc/shadow file. Thank you!